# Evaluate integral Maple

Tags: maple

I am trying to solve the following diff-equation:

$y'(t)−(3t+2)y(t) = 4e^{3t}$

I have found the solution manually and now I want to check my answer with Maple.
I have defined the diff-equation:

> L := D(y)(t) - (3*t^2 + 2)*y(t) = 4*exp(3*t)

Then I have found the solution:

y(t) = (Int(4*exp(-t*(t - 1)*(t + 1)), t) + _C1)*exp(t*(t^2 + 2))

Maple does not give me a reduced expression. As is seen in the result it gives an indefinite integral. How can I get maple to reduce the answer.

(I do not know how to make the commands in maple-style).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maple does not know how to evaluate this integral.

[image]

Here `value` switches `Int` to `int` and then Maple tries to evaluate.
It got the integral
$$
\int \frac{\exp(t)}{\exp({t^3})}\;dt
$$
but it did not succeed in evaluating it, so it left it in that form.